# How to enable MediaRouter Debug Mode?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am facing issue to discover ChromeCast devices, i need to enable Debug mode for MediaRouter.

I have not found any option on the documentationof android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable logging in the Cast SDK:

```
Cast.CastOptions apiOptions = Cast.CastOptions.builder(mSelectedDevice,
  mCastClientListener)
  .setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true)
  .build();
```